# How to set few parameter in the session of a jsf/primefaces application

Tags: session, jsf, primefaces, leaflet

I am new to JSF and primefaces. So please excuse me for bad understanding.

I have few parameters, which are retrieved on index.xhtml(starting page). How can I set these parameters into the session or in RequestParameterMap to retriever again in every other page and bean or from some other way.

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

I retrieve value from it. But I want these values to be set in session or in this map, or what would be the best way ? Because those are geolocation parameters, which I do not see in any other page except on starting index.xthml page.

Comment: Just use a session scoped bean to hold those values.

Comment: I did use SessionScoped bean. Initially, I am supplying hardcoded geopositions but later retrieving original geolocation from user request. I solved this issue by using  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap Here its possible to set parameters into SessionMap, which can be retrieved in the application elsewhere.

Comment: Session scoped beans behave the same and are more self-documenting. No need to manually fiddle with scoped maps from ExternalContext.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for your explaination but still quite abstract. Is there an alternative of above ? could you kindly be more elaborate if you explain